# How to add popup for landing page of my drupal site

Tags: drupal

Hi i would like to add a popup for landing page of drupal site i.e when a user visits my website they should get popup first.

How it can be done?can any one help me?

Thanks in advance,
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

1. enalbe PHP to be used in nodes
2. add <?php drupal_add_js('/path/to/myJavascirpt.js') ?> to your homepage, with PHP turned on
3. create file /path/to/myJavascirpt.js with contents:

   alert('Welcome to my website!');